# With pouchdb how to find how much storage space is used and how much is remaining

Tags: pouchdb

**Question:**

Iam building an offline web application using html5 and pouchdb.

I have to display how much storage space is used by application and how much space is left for my application to use.

I did check the pouchdb tutorials and api to find if there is any information around it. But couldn't find any info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser vendors unfortunately don't expose this information anywhere. It's really very mysterious. Even in the case of Safari's WebSQL, where they give you "allowances" of 5MB, 10MB, 50MB, etc., it's not clear how they calculate those megabytes. I've seen databases that were effectively the same size take up different amounts of space according to Safari's calculations, e.g. because they opened more database names (even if those databases were immediately deleted afterwards). Weird stuff.

Maybe the [HTML5 Quota Management API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/) (currently in draft) will help some day.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Just wondering how much will be roughly be the maximum space provided by IE11 browser on a windows tablet for storage.

Comment: There's been some research done on quotas (e.g. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/ and http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/24/indexeddb-and-limits-ie), but I'm not aware of anybody who's researched IE11 on tablets yet.

Comment: I am actually a bit worried now. I have built an offline application using pouchdb,html5, angularjs to bring a large amount of data from the server and store it to the local device and work offline. My target device is windows 8 tablets with IE Metro browsers.  I am very worried now, no clue how my application will behave when i start getting large datasets (images and pdfs as base64encoded strings). I was expecting that I should be able to store atleast 200mb of data within the browser using pouchdb.

Comment: I can't offer you much consolation except that PouchDB works with the databases that are available on the platform. :) There's no alternative to IndexedDB in the IE browser (except LocalStorage, which has even less space). However, if you're writing a Cordova app, you can use the [SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) to have unlimited data. It supports Windows 8. More info on limits is here: http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits